# Formatting date in rails so it matches another date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this var that has a date in it, It currently looks like this

```
10-10-2016
```

i need to make this change from that to this

```
10/10/2016
```

How do i go about this?

Heres the var.

```
 tmdate = row[10]
```

Comment: Is the variable an actual Date object or is it a string?

Answer (score 1):

If your want edit a `Date` object in Ruby, try this:

`Date.parse('10-10-2016').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: This answer shows how to format a Date object as a string. The asker was not clear on whether he had a string or an actual date object.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tr`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr)

```
"10-10-2016".tr("-","/")
=> "10/10/2016"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
  "10-10-2016".gsub('-', '/')
```

Comment: This works if he actually has a string, the asker implied he had a date object but wasn't clear

Comment: You can convert a date object to a string, then use above code to get the result

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
"10-10-2016".split('-').join('/')
```

Comment: your answer works if he's actually got a string, not if he's got a date though. When someone asks a question this basic it might be good to include a little explanation of what your code does / how it works.